# Is it possible to completely mask a password with JLine?

Tags: masking, jline, spring-shell

I'm using Spring Shell for a CLI and I want to read a password from the input line.
For such purpose spring shell has jline, so using the official documentation [1] of jline it suggests the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String password = new ConsoleReader().readLine('*');
    System.out.println("My password is: "+password);
}
```

When starting the application it looks like this:

```
mysecretpassword   << entered by myself 
****************   << masking from jline
My password is: mysecretpassword  << my output
```

So my question is what is the purpose of masking the password if it is shown anyway, when I type it?
Is there a possibility to do it Unix style and don't even show the password, while typing it?

[1] http://jline.sourceforge.net/#installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you tagged your question with spring-shell, there is an open [issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SHL-94) for support of masked (password) options.

Comment: thanks for the info, I will follow along with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, we implemented this feature directly (bypassing JLine) like so in Spring XD: (see `UserInput.prompt()`)
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/spring-xd-shell/src/main/java/org/springframework/xd/shell/command/ConsoleUserInput.java